# Telegraft (Javascript) : How do I return the function in telegram keyboard or inline keyboard?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I want to return a function
I tried replacing the "Yes"
It doesn't work,
when I look at the function itself,
it only accepts string,

thus I'm puzzled,
because if I use bot.hear in telegraf,
any person who says yes, will activate the command.

is there anyway to call a function ?

```
 bot.command("report", (ctx) => {
            ctx.reply("Are you sure? using this will have a refresh timeout of 2 minutes.", {
                reply_markup: {
                    keyboard: [
                        /* Inline buttons. 2 side-by-side */
                        [{ text: "Yes", callback_data: test() }, { text: "No", callback_data: "No" }],

                        /* One button */
                        [{ text: "Next", callback_data: "next" }],

                        /* Also, we can have URL buttons. */
                        [{ text: "Open in browser", url: "telegraf.js.org" }]
                    ]
                }
            });

        });
    const test = () => {
       console.log("test")
    }
```